# Limits and roots

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $n$ is a positive integer and $n \geq 2$, then

$\sqrt[n]{n} = 1 +h$, where $h \le \sqrt{2\over n-1}$ .

I was trying to do induction before but I kind of got stuck. Should I keep trying that?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $h>0$. We get by expansion
$$n=(1+h)^n=1+{n\choose 1}h+{n\choose 2}h^2+\ldots$$
where the terms hiding in the "$\ldots$" are $\ge 0$. Hence
$$ n-1=nh+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}h^2\ge (n-1)\cdot\frac n2h^2$$
which already gives us the stronger bound
$$h\le \sqrt{\frac2n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt[n]n=1+h\iff n=(1+h)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkh^k=1+nh+\frac{n(n-1)}2h^2+\ldots\ge\frac{n(n-1)}2h^2$$

Now, supposing the claim is false, we get

$$n\ge\frac{n(n-1)}2h^2>\frac{n(n-1)}2\frac2{n-1}=n$$

which is obviously a contradiction.